# Injecting data into the Windows entropy pool

Tags: windows, random, entropy, kernel

On Linux, it is possible for userspace to mix arbitrary data with the kernel entropy pool by writing to the `/dev/urandom` device. Is there any equivalent on Windows which does not require SYSTEM?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "does not require SYSTEM" ?

Comment: I ask because I found this particular link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/44fe31ad-750d-449e-99ea-989b8d94d693/adding-to-the-system-entropy-pool?forum=wdk which may or may not be useful to you based on what you mean by system

Comment: @Limit SYSTEM is a high privilege context, similar to root on Linux. I believe there are ways to register a new driver that acts as an RNG, but that is not what I am looking for because it requires these privileges. That link seems to describe _replacing_ the system RNG with your own provider, which is not what I want.

Comment: I see. Sure! Makes sense

Answer (score 4):

None that I know of, exactly. [`CryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx) (the legacy CryptoAPI CSPRNG function) allows callers to supply additional entropy, but it's not even clear if this affects future calls to `CryptGenRandom` by the same process, and it's fairly clear it doesn't affect other processes.

[`BCryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375458(v=vs.85).aspx) (the next-gen replacement for the old `CryptGenRandom`) *used* to allow the caller to supply addition entropy in much the same way, using the `BCRYPT_RNG_USE_ENTROPY_IN_BUFFER` flag, but that is no longer supported as of Win8. Even in Vista and Win7 (and Server 2008), though, it is unclear whether the data supplied with that flag only modified the data returned by that call, or that call and future results to calls from the same process, or future results for all callers.

Comment: `...it is unclear whether the data...` This is what I wanted to clarify. Although this answer is enlightening, "it is unclear" doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @forest Unfortunately, without access to the CAPI/CNG source code, and given the inherently random nature of the API, the only way to know is to check the documentation, hear from somebody who wrote it, or use decompilation. I once knew some people in CNG, but it was some time ago and I've lost touch; I'm somewhat interested in the decompilation but not deeply enough to do it myself right now, and the only documentation available is what I provided. Sorry...

Comment: Oh well. At least it's some information to go on. It would probably be possible to write to the registry random seed to affect the pool at next boot, but that of course would require being Administrator.